# Mysql query for winners in the contest including draws entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running contests on my website. Every contest could have multiple entries. I want to retrieve the best 3 entries or more (in the case of draw) based on the score.

The table is as follows:

```
contest_id    entry_id    score
1             1           21
1             2           50
1             3           34
1             4           50
1             5           10
1             6           21
1             7           13
1             8           21
```

The result should be (with draws):

```
entry_id   score
2          50
4          50
3          34
1          21
6          21
8          21
```

Comment: Order by score desc limit 3

Comment: limit 3 will bring only entries 2, 4, and 3. I want the entries with the best 3 scores.

Comment: You were asking for best 3 entries, if you want 6 then limit 6

Comment: "the best 3 entries or more (in the case of draw)".
I want to retrieve the draws entries, so limit will not work. Check the result table!

Comment: did the query worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Select E.entry_id, E.score 
   from entry  E
    JOIN ( 
      select  distinct score 
      from entry 
      order by score desc 
      LIMIT 3
      ) T
   ON E.score = T.score
   order by score
```

Comment: @SandroSimas, you are right, adding distinct fixes the issue. updated the answer

Comment: @SandroSimas, also i had to convert that into subquery join as in doesn't work. this is giving corect results http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9fc46/13

Comment: I will create another question similar to this, please check later. The difference is that the score column is in another table and must be summed to get the final score for the entry. It appears to be much more complex.